# i want to delete files with given extension

Tags: c#, dll, system

I want to develop a C# application that allows users to give an extension (example: *.mp3) And then the application will remove all files that contains this extension from the hard disk.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? And what is your question?

Comment: i just need the library that i need to use and the methode

Comment: use System.IO.File.Delete

Comment: File.Delete() will do

Comment: _"From the hard disk"_ means from all drives, even network shares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example to delete files with .msi extension in C drive,

```
DirectoryInfo Dr = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] files = Dr.GetFiles("*.msi").Where(p => p.Extension == ".msi").ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    try
    {
        file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
        File.Delete(file.FullName);
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
```

To get all extensions,

```
public List<FileInfo> GetFiles(string path, params string[] extensions)
{
    List<FileInfo> list = new List<FileInfo>();
    foreach (string ext in extensions)
        list.AddRange(new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*" + ext).Where(p =>
              p.Extension.Equals(ext,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
              .ToArray());
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put needed path in below code and use a foreach and File.Delete.

Use

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)` :

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var item in files)
{
   try
   {
       File.Delete(item);
   }
   catch (Exception)
   { //log exception}
}
```